# Cache directory doesn't exist

Tags: android, caching, memory-management

how is it possible that `context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()` returns `null`? As far as I know the internal cache directory should always exist.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks similar to what you are experiencing, but there's no fix on the bug yet: http://goo.gl/zipcZ

Comment: Thanks for the link! I had that bug a couple of times in my app as well when upgrading, but I wasn't sure that it was an Android bug (but I suspected it) :) I don't know if the two bugs are related, but comment 11 would suggest that it could be possible that for an application the cache directory is `null`

Comment: If it's your code and not something canned like webview, can you check for the apparent bug and substitute the app-private internal storage directory?  Or if it's not a concern, the shared external storage?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a valid Context, is that even possible?

Comment: @nmr: never heard of something like that honestly

Comment: Maybe your context is null;I hava made a simple mistake, I hope you were not;

Answer (score 7):

maybe it returns null since you don't have enough internal storage? try to also use [getExternalCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29)

also , if it doesn't work , simply go to the path.

the standard is that it should give you the path "/data/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/cache/" , and if you want the external storage cache , it should give you the path "EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PATH/Android/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME/cache/" .

Comment: Remember if you are using an emulator to do this, make sure your emulator is emulating external memory like SD card

Answer (score 2):

Reading the thread posted at http://goo.gl/zipcZ it appears that an uninstall and re-install of the application resolves the issue in many cases. Additionally reading the thread, it does not appear that this is something you can fix as its an internal issue on some devices.

Comment: It's possibly an issue that is visible just on some devices, unfortunately I don't have the bug reports any more and I cannot double check this theory