# java.lang.NullPointerException when use context.getExternalCacheDir();

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-file

Currently in my Application I have been reported of NullPointerExceptions when I use
context.getExternalCacheDir(), the NullPointerException happens in !cacheDir.exists(), the cacheDir is null and in this point throws NullPointerException;

What it is strange is that previously I check if the external storage is mounted. Here is the code:

```
public FileCache(Context context){
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir= context.getExternalCacheDir();
    // sometimes return null even the external storage mounted
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists()) // if cacheDir is null throws NullPointerException
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}
```

Note that in my androidManifest.xml I have the permission for write in external storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Please can you post here the logcat output?

Comment: when you get a NullPointerException on `context.getExternalCacheDir()` that means that `context` is `null`, not the return value

Comment: Thrakbad that could be the reason, but the nullpointerexception is throwed when the app try to run the cacheDir.exists() the cacheDir is null

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood that part. Have you tried if `context.getExternalFilesDir()` is also `null`? Btw. from what I gather from the documentation, if the cache dir doesn't exist, `getCacheDir()/getExternalCacheDir()` will always return `null`. So `cacheDir.exists()` would never fail if `cacheDir` is not `null`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4441849/813951

Comment: There's also an [issue in Google code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18702)

Comment: Thrakbad the context that I pass in the Argument is the applicationContext... and I am creating this object in the onCreate of MyApplication extends Application.

Comment: how did u test yr code? I mean in a real device or emulator. if u did test in a emulator please give some value to sdcard size for instance: 32 MiB